# How responsive is ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, responsive, android-constraintlayout

As I read in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#add-a-constraint) you should be able to build a responsive layout. 
 
Let's say we have two views : **A** and **B** 
**If** you are using the app on a **tablet**, **A** should be placed **left of B**.
**If** you are using the app on a **smartphone**, **A** should be placed **above B**.
Is it possible in this way?

Comment: I'd make two different layouts in this case.

Comment: This is why the resource system allows you to define different layouts for different sizes and different orientations.  Use multiple layouts.  I'd even say you don't want it to be based on just tablet/smartphone-  plenty of people use tablets portrait mode, especially for reading.

Comment: Ok, ty for your answers. I hoped that would be possible though i would do different layouts.

Comment: Depending on how much complicated the layout is it can be done with some small code tweak. If you have **two** containers/views and nothing else I can post answer but anything more beyond this you should use different different layout.